# java.time discovering I'm in the daylight savings "gap"

Tags: java, datetime, time

I have a delivery time window from 01:40 to 2:10 every day. That's a LocalTime
In UK we have daylight savings time and if I use

```
ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate(2015, 3, 29), LocalTime.of(1, 40), ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
```

I get 02:40 on the day in question because the switch to daylight savings causes a gap.
But then I end up with a negative delivery time window of 2:40 - 2:10 on the day in question.
I guess I can detect this by converting back to LocalTime to see if my hours have stayed the same, but is there a smarter way of spotting my local to zoned datetime conversion has fallen "in the gap"?

And if I have fallen in the gap how do I find out what the gap actually is - in this case 1:00 - 2:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this query:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.of(2015, 3, 29).atTime(LocalTime.of(1, 40)); 
ZoneOffsetTransition conflict = ZoneId.of("Europe/London").getRules().getTransition(ldt);
boolean gap = (conflict != null) && conflict.isGap(); // true
```

Attention: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getTransition-java.time.LocalDateTime-) is not correct, but the code example works.

About your second question:

You can ask the conflict transition. It offers the methods `getDateTimeAfter()` and `getDateTimeBefore()` returning the appropriate local timestamp of type `LocalDateTime`.