# Exception when executing JDBC query - Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition with Logstash

Tags: java, jdbc, logstash, jodatime

I have the following JDBC input:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    id => "mypipeline"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/drivers/mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar"
    jdbc_connection_string => "my-connection-string"
    jdbc_password => "my-user"
    jdbc_user => "my-pass"
    jdbc_fetch_size => 5000
    schedule => "*/5 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT l.id, l.name, l.log_date FROM logs l WHERE l.created_at >= :sql_last_value"
  }
}
```

The log_date column is as follows:

```
log_date DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

Warning; `created_at` and `log_date` are not the same column. The query that's being executed is as follows:

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, l.log_date FROM logs l WHERE l.created_at >= '1970-01-01 02:00:00'
```

which is wrong, since Istanbul does not go into DST, should be `'1970-01-01 03:00:00'` For values such as `1949-04-10` for log_date, I am receiving this error:

```
[2023-06-02T11:50:30,470][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][mypipeline] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>Sequel::DatabaseError, :message=>"Java::OrgJodaTime::IllegalInstantException: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 1949-04-10T00:00:00.000 (Europe/Istanbul)", :cause=>"#<Java::OrgJodaTime::IllegalInstantException: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 1949-04-10T00:00:00.000 (Europe/Istanbul)>"}
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition*" - Istanbul does not *currently* change between daylight saving time and standard time, but [it has done in the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Turkey).

It is currently observing what is effectively DST year-round - and has done so since March 27th 2016, when the clocks moved forward by 1 hour from a UCT timezone offset of +2 hours to +3 hours.

---

More specifically regarding the "*Illegal instant*" error: In 1949 on 10th April at midnight, the clocks moved forward by 1 hour - so the local time of `1949-04-10  00:00` never actually happened. That is why it is a "gap" value, as noted in the error message.

This time zone data is captured in the IANA [Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (TZDB), which I assume is what your application uses, behind the scenes (e.g. if you are using Joda-Time).

You can use an online tool such as [this one](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/turkey/istanbul?year=1949) (and probaby others):

[image]

**WARNING** - I cannot vouch for the accuracy of the data on this web site, but it does match the TZDB rule for *this specific example*, which I extracted as follows using Java (which uses TZDB data):

```
 - on 1949-04-10 at 00:00
 - the clocks moved forward by 1 hr (daylight saving)
 - from TZ offset +02:00 to offset +03:00
```

---

Regarding your comment:

> "*should be '1970-01-01 03:00:00'*"

For 1970, the TZDB indicates that there were no adjustments made. So, the effective offset from UTC was the one previously made in 1964:

```
 - on 1964-10-01 at 00:00
 - the clocks moved back by 1 hr
 - from TZ offset +03:00 to offset +02:00
```

And that `+02:00` is what you are (correctly) seeing in your data for that 1970 datetime.

---

If you want to avoid using a datetime which falls into one of these gaps (caused by the clocks moving forward), then you can do that programmatically - for example:

- Assuming Java (since you mention Joda-Time): [java.time discovering I'm in the daylight savings "gap"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32862926/12567365)

Other mainstream languages should have similar capabilities.

---

Also, since you mentioned Joda, maybe you can consider using Java's `java.time` classes now (if you have a suitable version of Java), [instead of using Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

---

**Specific solution to the case with Logstash**

Adding `jdbc_default_timezone => "GMT"` to Logstash configuration and altering the timezone of the host machine will make Logstash to query the database without getting this error.

Comment: Actually, Turkey is in permanent Daylight Saving Time (DST). Current year-round offset is +03:00. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Turkey  So your first sentence is misleading. Otherwise, good Answer.

Comment: @andrewJames I understand. However, I do not have the control of the source code, so what I did was to run logstash in GMT, and the error disappeared.

Comment: @BasilBourque that is correct. However, this was not the case before 2016, where Turkey altered between DST/non-DST.

Comment: @andrewJames Your answer put me in the right direction, so I edited it to include a solution for the issue with Logstash and accepted your answer. Thanks.